# Can't Set NODE_ENV to production with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack 2.2.1 to build a react-redux app for production, but can't seem to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production`.

Here is webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  'axios', 'lodash', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux',
  'react-router', 'redux', 'redux-form', 'redux-thunk'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

And here are my scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
}
```

When I run `npm run build`, my bundle.js is compiled but it's not for production. In my webpack.config.js, I replaced the option for the DefinePlugin to `'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'` and it worked. So I'm thinking there is something wrong with my package.json file, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: It works for me with export.

"build": "export NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p",

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you know why I need export here, since in other scripts, I haven't needed to use export?

Comment: i seriously dont know why this doesnt work.. it works fine for me without export. this is my build script: cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server --progress --color

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are running two processes with your build command `npm run clean` and `webpack -p`. When you add `NODE_ENV=production` in front, it only applies to the current process. In you example, `NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p`, only the `clean` command runs with the set environment variable.

When you add `export NODE_ENV=production` it will set it for all processes you start from that terminal. Keep this in mind because everything else you run from that same terminal window will have `NODE_ENV=production` set.

```
$ npm run build
> NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p
...
$ echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

If you don't want to have `NODE_ENV=production` to stick for other processes, then add `NODE_ENV=production` in front of both processes:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. However, this worked: `webpack --env.NODE_ENV=production`!

Comment: Thanks Derk, this seems to more inline with the webpack documentation as well: https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/#root

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman that seems to now give the sam eerror unknown argument as before. Looking for a solution now

Answer (score 0):

Passing NODE_ENV like below adds a space at the end

```
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && webpack -p",
```

Trim it before using the value

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()
```